# Deploying MVC site to IIS results in it cannot find default shared partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a site that works perfectly on my local IIS.

All my pages uses a default shared partial view, which is called the expected `_Layout.cshtml`. This view is placed in my Shared folder. This can be seen here:

[image]

This works perfectly, as I would expect.

However, I now publish my website. Then, some of my pages outside the `HomeController`, results in a :

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Search/Index.aspx
~/Views/Search/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Search/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Search/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

This is of course true, but I would expect it to search for `_Layout.cshtml` in my shared folder, and not these file names.

What can I do to solve it? And why does it work on my local IIS, and not on production?

Comment: Why would call to a default action search for `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla excuse me, what do you mean?

Comment: Do you have any custom routes set up?

Comment: The error suggests it cant find the View `Index` (not necessarily `_Layout`). Does The `Index` method on `SearchController` return `View();` or have you hard coded a path?

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard why would you expect it to search for _Layout.chtml in your shared folder? Once the _Layout.chtml is downloaded, it uses only RenderAction() etc, methods to parse this Search/Index.chtml, OldAds/Index.chtml, etc files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out there problem was somewhere else entirely.

It turned out many of the old views had set "Built action" to "None". That resulted in my views not existing, and then it simply could not find them.

The error makes sense, but I had not seen that this was the actual problem!