# The view or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations error at Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.5

Tags: model-view-controller, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

MVC application is working fine in VS2017. When I publish application to Windows 8 IIS 8.5 it's also fine. But when I publish it to Windows Server 2012 R2 it is firing an exception

```
~/Views/Home/statroom.aspx
~/Views/Home/statroom.ascx
~/Views/Shared/statroom.aspx
~/Views/Shared/statroom.ascx
~/Views/Home/statroom.cshtml
~/Views/Home/statroom.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/statroom.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/statroom.vbhtml
```

My code :

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult StatRoom()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

My View \Views\Home\StatRoom.cshtml

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>StatRoom</title>
    <link href="~/Styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="div11">
            <img id="photo" src="~/Images/Default.jpg" height="100%" 
width="100%">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
    <div id="div21">
        </br>
        </br>
        <h id="hd1"> 2321 </h>
        <div id="div211">
            <h id="hd2">  </h>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="div3">

    <div id="div311">
        <p id="hp">TITLE</p>
        <div id="div312">
            <br />
            <h id="hd3">NAME SURNAME </h>
            <br />
            <hr style="width: 300px;" />
            <br />
            <h id="branch"> DIVISION</h>
            <div id="div313">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



</div>

<div id="div4">
    <div id="div41">

        <h id="h4" style="color: white;">    </h>
        <div id="div412">
            <h id="hd" style="color: white;"> </h>
            <br />
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {


    $.connection.hub.start();
    var chat = $.connection.triggerHub;

    chat.client.privateMessage = function (messageID, action, message) {
        console.log(messageID);
        console.log(action);
        console.log(message);
        switch (action){
            case 1:
                Init(message);
                break;
            case 2:
                window.location.reload(true);
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = message; 
                break;
        }


    };

});
function Init(message) {
    try {
        var res = JSON.parse(message);
        $('#hd1').text(res.roomnr);
        $('#hd3').text(res.doctorname);
        $('#hp').text(res.title);
        $('#branch').text('-' + res.branch + '-');
        if (res.photourl !== '')
            $("#photo").attr('src', res.photourl);
        else
            $("#photo").attr('src', '~/Images/Default.jpg');
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}

</script>
```

Same code, same published files, but not working. I am sending data from server to client as JSON format, that is why I do not pass model data from controller to view.

### Additional note

I have removed Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform from references (because I got error in server for that dll), and system.codedom section from web config. But I am not sure is problem related to this issue or not. Also created new MVC VS template application, deployed it and same result.

Comment: Have you checked the folder permissions on the server to make sure the account IIS is using can access all the files?

Comment: I have, I have set credentials of application as admin user, also checked folders and subfolders. They are also full righted to same user

Comment: Are you deploying directly from Visual Studio? If so it could be the build action on the files. There is a similar post here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25935375/6392962

Comment: I deployed it directly from Visual Studio, then copied folder pasted to Server.

Comment: Sorry to ask the stupid comment, but you're 100% sure that all files copied over and nothing was corrupted during the transfer? Have you tried replacing just the files in question etc? Sorry, I know it's an obvious thing to check, but just making sure.

Comment: It is normal question @Marmalade :) I have copied many times. It is another issue I think. Now I am upgrading my VS to latest version. Then will try to remove roslyn folder and post about result.

Comment: No problem, let me know how it goes. If I can help, I will.